# How can I find a character at the 3rd last index of its occurrence in an overall string and add another character before it?

Tags: mysql, substring

I have a database full of important information... I need to change the information to fit a new format...

The current information follows this format... (Note this is all inserted in one cell)

```
DataString1:SomeOtherString1:MoreString1|DataString2:SomeOtherString2:MoreString2|DataString3:SomeOtherString3:MoreString3
```

I need to be able to do the following...
1) Locate all of the '|' symbols.
2) For each '|' symbol I need to find the second ':' before it.
3) Insert another ':' before the results of step 2.

I can accomplish this through code in another language like PHP for example but I would like to be able to do it via SQL.

The above example would turn into this... (I bolded the changes...)

```
DataString1::SomeOtherString1:MoreString1|DataString2::SomeOtherString2:MoreString2|DataString3::SomeOtherString3:MoreString3
```

I ended up just making a PHP script to do this, I'm not even sure what I wanted was entirely possible with MySQL as there was over 30 instances of | in each cell, and over 180 instances of ':' in each cell.... If anyone has an answer feel free to post and if it works Ill vote it as best answ

Comment: Fwiw I'd do this in php too

Answer (score 0):

In sql the substring can be used like this substring(expression,startposition, length), If your occurence is repeating then you will have to create an update script which will check the substring postion at the character length lets say

```
 DataString1
```

Here position of S is 5, you should count the occurence of | and save this on to a variable

```
select @sd substring (column_name ,start,length) from table where --conditons
Update table set column_name = '' where substring (column_name ,start,length) = '|'
```

you have to get the occurance of @sd and do the math to concatinate the string and update your cells

Comment: I can't rely on math as the data stored is always of different sizes... So I need to be able to locate the second ':' before each '|' and place an extra ':' before each second last ':'

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just making a PHP script to do this, I'm not even sure what I wanted was entirely possible with MySQL as there was over 30 instances of | in each cell, and over 180 instances of ':' in each cell.... If anyone has an answer feel free to post and if it works Ill vote it as best answer.